# Ansible creating cronjob every 10sec

Tags: cron, ansible

I want to know if there is any way to create a ansible playbook able to run a cronjob every 10sec.
Thanks all for your answers

Comment: you want to use ansible to create a cron job that will be firing every 10 seconds, or explicitly run an existing cron job every 10 seconds?

Comment: use ansible to create a cron job that will be firing every 10 seconds :D

Comment: you could use the [cron module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/cron_module.html), as an alternative, `lineinfile` module could be used too.

Answer (score 0):

Cron only has resolution down to minutes.  The best you can get out of cron is once per minute.  To get once every ten seconds, you'll need a script that will run your task and then wait ten seconds, and repeat it 6 times.  If you have that script, you can use cron to run it every minute.  And of course, you can use the Ansible cron job to set it up on your servers.

Answer (score -3):

Task to create a Cron Job

```
- name: Sets cron job to run script per minute
  cron:
    name: Sets cron job to run script per minute
    minute: "*"
    hour: "*"
    day: "*"
    month: "*"
    weekday: "*"
    user: "centos"
    job: sh sample.sh > sample.out 2>&1
```

cron module parameters explained:

- minute, hour, day, month, and weekday are configured to specify the cronjob interval at which the job should be executed
- user: the user for which the cronjob should be configured
- job: the operation to be performed

As we can see that the minimum we can set is per minute. So, to run the operation per 10 seconds, we need to add that support in the script.

Sample script sample.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while sleep 10; do
  echo "Running after a sleep of 10s"
  # Add the business logic here
done
```

Now, this script will get triggered every minute by the cronjob and the script in turn will run the business logic every 10 sec.